# Accessing barcode reader on an MC9200 through asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode-scanner

I have temporary acquired a MC9200 barcode scanner to test some software we are integrating into our business.

The software runs on a webpage and knowing that, all sorts of ideas are coming to my mind to develop custom based barcode solutions for the company.

So I made a simple ASP.NET webpage that contains just a textbox and a label and hosted it on our IIS server, and pointed the MC9200 barcode scanner to the website address.
It loads just fine, but pressing the barcode scanner trigger does not shoot out a barcode laser.

It's as if I need to some how initialize the scanner to be used - which makes sense thinking about it now.

Any suggestions on where I need to focus my research to use this barcode scanner on an ASP.NET webpage?

Thanks

EDIT
After some investigation, I realized with help from @John that the barcode reader doesn't send out a laser on the trigger press at all (even before the webpage is loaded). I believe that something on the barcode reader is initializing the barcode reader to be used for applications.

Comment: Does the scanner scan without the webpage?

Comment: @John No it does not. If I run the software on the device that we are integrating into our business, then the barcode scanners laser appears.

Perhaps now, some other software is starting the laser.

Currently investigating

Comment: That is strange. All the laser does is read a barcode and scan convert to text. Therefore with a textbox it should read the barcode and input the string representative into that box. The problem is not the webpage, it is the scanner, it should work in a way that pressing the trigger emits a powerful (not deadly) laser to read, no matter what applications are open

Comment: @John I see where you are coming from. I believe the software that runs to use this scanner for it's correct purposes somehow initializes the scanner, then starts up the intended webpage for usage.  
Because I am trying to build my own software and simply pointing the web browser to my website, its completely bypassing the Initializing stage.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it.

It turns out the software on the scanner initializes the barcode reader then starts up an webpage for the software we are integrating.

I modified the URL that the software uses to my own webpage and now it loads with bar-coding capability.